# Configure Eureka and Zuul to redirect connection to @RestController

Tags: netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I have 2 simple projects that I want to integrate. One is composed by Zuul and Eureka, while the other one is a simple web project.

I want to redirect all requests from localhost:8761/books to localhost:8081. I have, for example, a endpoint localhost:8081/test that I would like to access through localhost:8761/books/test

When I start both applications, I can see that my Web project registrates in Eureka (BOOK   n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 10.0.1.5:book:8081), but when I access localhost:8761/books/test, I get the exception appended at the end of this post. Here are the basic configurations.

### Web project

#### build.grade:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
...
```

#### bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.application.name=book
server.port=8081
```

### Zuul/Eureka project

#### build.grade:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul')
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
...
```

#### application.properties:

```
zuul.routes.book.path=/books/**
zuul.routes.book.service-id=book

server.port=8761

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

#### Exception:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:158) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:79) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.jav[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframeworklter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErroValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: book
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:468) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscratMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:131) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:76) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:83) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:49) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:268) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:75) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8553) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8520) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        aservables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:433) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:332) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:102) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:81) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RestClientRibbonCommand.forward(RestClientRibbonCommand.java:135) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RestClientRibbonCommand.run(RestClientRibbonCommand.java:106) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RestClientRibbonCommand.run(RestClientRibbonCommand.java:50) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:293) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:289) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
       internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
       internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8553) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8520) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:57) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:401) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:373) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:329) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:127) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
        ... 68 common frames omitted
```